# Como fazer para o menu não ser atropelado pelo scroller do iPhone?

Tags: javascript, css3, ios, mobile, safari

No navegador do Safari / ou chrome na versão mobile iPhone, aparece uma barra de rolamento em cima do menu, existe uma maneira de resolver isso quando for iPhone?

**SCSS:**

```
@mixin getSideRadius($side:'normal', $radius:0) {
     @if ($side != 'normal') {
        border-#{$side}-radius:$radius;
        -webkit-border-#{$side}-radius:$radius;  
        -moz-border-#{$side}-radius:$radius; 
        -ms-border-#{$side}-radius:$radius;
     } @else {
        border-radius:$radius;
        -webkit-border-radius:$radius;  
        -moz-border-radius:$radius; 
        -ms-border-radius:$radius;
     }
  }

@mixin getMenu() {
  $black5: #595a5c;
  $black4: #86878b;
  $black2: #dee1e6;
  $black1: #f3f6fd;
  $black_bg: #f9fbff;
  $id_green: #96dd48;
  $size_mobile:768px;
  $white:#fff;
  $spacing_12:12px;
  $size_mobile_small:480px;
  $size_mobile_medium:580px;
  $size_desktop_small:800px;
  
    //MENU PRINCIPAL
    .menu-dropdown-base {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background: $white;
        height: 48px;
        display: flex;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 23;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-top: 1px solid $black2;
    }
   
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal  {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: flex;
       justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 5px 0.51px;
        padding: 0 4.2px;
        text-align: center;
    }


   .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 0 4px;
        padding: 0 4px;
        text-align: center;   
   }
   @media(min-width:400px) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
            margin: 0 2vw;
            padding: 0 4px;
            text-align: center;   
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:440px) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
            margin: 0 4vw;
            padding: 0 4px;
            text-align: center;   
        }
    }

   

     .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a {
         display: block;
         padding: 2px;
         width: 100%;
     }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a > span {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: $black5;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 12.8px;
        display: flex;
        padding-top: 2px;
    }

    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.active a span,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.active a i {
        color: $id_green;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a i {
        font-size: 17px;
        color: $black5;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-notificacoes,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-mais,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-explorar {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu-account-user ul.drop-user-menu li.message-item-menu  > a,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-producao-textual,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-painel-educador,
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-favoritos, 
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-tarefas {
        display: none;
    }

    .footer-content .menu-footer ul {
        display: flex;
    }
    .footer-content .menu-footer ul li {
       margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .footer-content .footer-menu-position {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .footer-content .menu-footer ul li > a {
        display: inline-flex;
        border: 1px $black2 solid;
        @include getSideRadius('normal', 10px);
        padding: $spacing_12;
        color: $black4;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 16px;
        &:hover {
            background: $black_bg;
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:$size_mobile_small) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 0 4.5vw;
        padding: 0 4px;
        text-align: center;   
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:$size_mobile_medium) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 0 5vw;
        padding: 0 4px;
        text-align: center;   
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:600px) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 0 5vw;
        padding: 0 4px;
        text-align: center;   
        }
    }
  

   @media(min-width: $size_mobile) {
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal {
        margin-left: 16px;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

   }

   @media(max-width: $size_desktop_small) and (min-width:$size_mobile) {
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li {
            margin: -1.1vw; 
            padding: 0 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:$size_mobile) {
        //saindo do mobile... 
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a:hover  {
            background: $black1;
        }

        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.active a span,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.active a i {
            color: $id_green;
        }
        
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a {
            @include getSideRadius('normal', 10px);
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }

        
        .menu-dropdown-base {
            border-top: none;
            bottom: inherit;
            top: 60px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $black2;
            justify-content:left;
            z-index: 11;
        }
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a {
            display: flex
        }
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li a span {
            font-size: 12.8px;
            line-height: 12.8px;
            margin-left: 8px;
            margin-top: 2px;
        }
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-notificacoes,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-mais,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-explorar {
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-account-user ul.drop-user-menu li.message-item-menu  > a,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-producao-textual,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-painel-educador,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-favoritos,
        .menu-dropdown-base ul.nav-menu-principal li.menu-tarefas {
            display: flex;
        }
    }
}
@include getMenu();
```

**HTML do menu:**

```
<div class="menu-dropdown-base">
    <div id="menubar" class="menu-list">
        <ul class="nav-menu-principal">
            <li class="menu-home active" style=""><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-home"></i><span>Início</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-favoritos"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-favorite"></i><span>Favoritos</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-tarefas"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-clipboard-content"></i><span>Tarefas</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-producao-textual"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-pencil-paintbrush"></i><span>Produções</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-conquistas"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-medal"></i><span>Conquistas</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-explorar"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-keypad"></i><span>Explorar</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-notificacoes"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-school-bell"></i><span>Notificações</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-mais"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-menu"></i><span>Mais</span></a </li>
            <li class="menu-painel-educador ng-scope"><a href="#"><i class="combo icon-graduation-cap"></i><span>Painel do Educador</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo básico no [codePen](https://codepen.io/ivanferrer/pen/mdPyQEy), só está sem os ícones, porque não precisa para isso... O que quero saber é se existe alguma forma de ajustar se for só no IPhone... eu sei que existe uma forma de identificar o notch, mas desconheço para reconhecer iphone.

> Estou procurando uma solução que pode ser em CSS ou em Javascript.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Acho que encontrei a solução:

```
:root {
  --ion-safe-area-top: 20px;
  --ion-safe-area-bottom: 22px;       
}
```

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/19060